# 標準入力から受け取った値で乗算すると TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python

税抜価格から税込価格を求めるコードを書いてるのですが計算するところでつまずきます。
型変換したりしましたが上手く行きませんでした。

```
a = input("入力してください。")
b = 1.08
sum = a * b
print(sum)
```

エラー

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: 型変換して駄目だったときのコードを開示してください。

Comment: 今回の原因ではないかもしれませんが、`sum`という関数/メソッドにも存在する(しうる)一般的な名前を変数(あるいは自作の関数/クラス/メソッド)の名前に使うのはやめた方が良いと思われます。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://qiita.com/xnpgofqfo/questions/85bd28a5cf633f9d89ef) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: 上記コメントの他サイトに付いた回答で解決すると思われますが、今後の質問の際にはエラーメッセージを最後の一行だけに端折って提示するのではなく表示された内容を全て表示されたまま質問に記載するようにしてください。どの行の何でエラーになったか等の重要な情報が表示されている場合もありますので。

Answer (score 2):

```
a = input("入力してください。")
```

を

```
a = int(input("入力してください。"))
```

にしてください．

Answer (score 1):

一回str型ではなくfloat型にしてみるとうまくいきます
サンプルです

```
try:
    a_str = input("入力してください。") #これはstr
    a = float(a_str) #floatにする
    b = 1.08
    Sum = a * b
    print(Sum)
except ValueError: #もし数にできなかったら
    print("エラー。数を入力してください。")
```